# phpexcel: Set style from function

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I set all cell styles/options from a function?

This code doesn't work for me:

```
function setStyleTest() {
    global $objPHPExcel, $cell;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $cell )->getFont()->setSize( 10 );
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $cell )->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
}

$cell = "A1";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $cell, 'Some content' );

setStyleTest();
```

But this works:

```
$cell = "A1";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $cell, 'Some content' );
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $cell )->getFont()->setSize( 10 );
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $cell )->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

And yeah, I don't know a lot about classes =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both of you code examples work, the issue is with the variable $cell. It needs to be an string that corresponds to an cell within the spreadsheet. For example to access cell A1, change $cell like so:

```
$cell = "A1";
```

As it stands your function setStyleTest() will always set the same static cell each time, in order to use it dynamically I would recommend this:

```
$cell = "A1";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $cell, 'Some content' );
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $cell )->getFont()->setSize( 10 );
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $cell )->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 

function setStyleTest($incomingCell) {
  global $objPHPExcel;
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $incomingCell )->getFont()->setSize( 10 );
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle( $incomingCell )->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
  //I added BOLD to make this easier to see the difference
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($incomingCell)->getFont()->setBold(true);
}

$cell2 = "B1";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue( $cell2, 'Some content2' );

setStyleTest($cell2);
```

Comment: I missed to tell, that `cellNavigation()` returns the needed string. It's an old project which I'd like to improve. Also the cell string arrived in `setStyleTest()`. The problem must be somewhere else. I'll upgrade the phpexcel version